# Many to many with attributes (sonata_type_collection) in sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have two entities Ventes and Article with many to many relationship and in the entity relation is ventes_article that have the attribut "quantite" :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ventes
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ventes")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VentesRepository")
 */
class Ventes
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    #......................



    /**
     * Many Articles have Many paks.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="Ventes")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ventes_article")
     */
    private $articles;





    /**
     * Add article
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Article $article
     *
     * @return Ventes
     */
    public function addArticle(\AppBundle\Entity\Article $article)
    {
        $this->articles[] = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove article
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Article $article
     */
    public function removeArticle(\AppBundle\Entity\Article $article)
    {
        $this->articles->removeElement($article);
    }

    /**
     * Get articles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getArticles()
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }

    #.............................
    #..........
}
```

and this is my entity Article :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Many packs have Many article.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ventes", mappedBy="Article")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ventes_article")
     */
    private $ventes;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ventes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->packs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


#/............



/**
 * Add vente
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ventes $vente
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function addVente(\AppBundle\Entity\Ventes $vente)
{
    $this->ventes[] = $vente;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove vente
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ventes $vente
 */
public function removeVente(\AppBundle\Entity\Ventes $vente)
{
    $this->ventes->removeElement($vente);
}

/**
 * Get ventes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getVentes()
{
    return $this->ventes;
    }

}
```

and in my class `VentesAdmin` I have :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class VentesAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{



    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper


        ->with('Acticles', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
        ->add('articles', 'sonata_type_model', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Article',
            'property' => 'reference',
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ))


        ->end()
        ;
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {

    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

    }



    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {

    }

}
```

in result :

[image]

but I want to show this result with costum attributes for same Article :

[image]

can you help me ??

Comment: Not sure about Sonata, but Symfony and Doctrine are not built for this (instead, use sth like Ventes <-> VentesArticle (own entity) <-> Article)

Comment: I am using it
( VentesArticle )

Comment: No, you have a ManyToMany between Ventes and Article, you'd need ManyToMany between Ventes and VentesArticle and ManyToMany between VentesArticle and Article. But I have no experience with Sonata, so I am not the best to help

Comment: It's a good practice to use nouns in singular for the class names. Even if you want to keep the names in French, it would be better `class Vente` instead of `class Ventes`. Or call it `class Sale` in English. The property in `class Article` should stay `ventes` because it is a Many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 1):

So, in this case we have a collection.

Predicate:

> Each Article can belongs to different Venteses and One Ventes contains
>   a lot of different articles.

This is Many-To-Many.
And each article has different attributes. For this purposes we have to use

> sonaty_type_collection

example for the `configureFormFields` function:

```
class OwnerAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    // ...

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('articles', 'sonata_type_collection', [
                  'required'      => false,
                  'label'         => 'Article',
                  'btn_add'       => true,
                  'btn_catalogue' => 'admin',
                  'type_options'  => [
                      'delete' => true,
                  ],
              ], [
                  'edit'          => 'inline',
                  'inline'        => 'table',
                  'sortable'      => 'id',
                  'allow_delete'  => true,
                  'placeholder'   => $this->trans('admin.placeholder.no_article'),
              ])
         ;
    }
}
```

You will have ability to add as many articles or whatever you want and with any number of attributes. See screens: 
[image]
[image]